# Server side Tab control in ASP.NET ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

Is there any .NET server side Tab control ?

I need something like this :

[image]

And I need it to be a server side control Tab ,and not a client side , for 
the sole purpose of navigation , when you navigate to a specific tab - only then 
get the data that is needed , and not on the first load .

Thanks

Comment: Hi check https://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxNavigationAndLayoutDemos/TabControl/ServerSide.aspx

Comment: @AishvaryaKarthik: It's not free , I need a free server side control , thanks .

Comment: You can achieve this by not using server side control. Do not load all tab data at once (first load), but only first tab. Then on click (on active) load the other tabs data.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by using a client side object but assign runat = 'server',
So, the event is fired only if post back occurs. 
Example:

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnCancel" Style="z-index: 176; left: 938px; position: absolute; top: 12px"
            runat="server>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using custom web UI control you can develop your requirement.

Please refer [Web-Tab-Control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/192844/Web-Tab-Control) article to create.